# How can I sort List<Map<String, dynamic>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list=[
{_id: 1, product_name: Name1, product_company: T, product_barcode: 1, product_shopping_date: 1610467398845, product_expiration_date: 1610414640000, product_origin_country: Musterherstellungsland, product_kind_of_crowd: Stück, product_availability: 1}, 
{_id: 2, product_name: Name2, product_company: T, product_barcode: 1, product_shopping_date: 1610467518522, product_expiration_date: 1610406000000, product_origin_country: Musterherstellungsland, product_kind_of_crowd: Stück, product_availability: 1}, 
{_id: 3, product_name: Name3, product_company: T, product_barcode: 1, product_shopping_date: 1610467551377, product_expiration_date: 1610423280000, product_origin_country: Musterherstellungsland, product_kind_of_crowd: Stück, product_availability: 1}]
```

How can I sort this list by product_expiration_date ?

I have tried this

```
list.sort((a, b) {
      return (a['product_expiration_date']).compareTo(b['product_expiration_date']);
    });
```

But this was the result:

```
E/flutter (  617): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: read-only
E/flutter (  617): #0      QueryResultSet.[]= (package:sqflite_common/src/collection_utils.dart:108:5)
E/flutter (  617): #1      Sort._insertionSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:70:10)
E/flutter (  617): #2      Sort._doSort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:58:7)
E/flutter (  617): #3      Sort.sort (dart:_internal/sort.dart:33:5)
E/flutter (  617): #4      ListMixin.sort (dart:collection/list.dart:355:10)
...
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: What are the results of what you have tried?

Comment: you can put `as int` like `(a['product_expiration_date'] as int)`

Comment: Your list is already sorted.

Comment: Please copy-paste your error messages with the provided formatting tools. **Do not** add them to your question as an image.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't let me put any more code in my post.

Comment: That's for a reason. Add more explanation about what you're trying to do and what problems you have to balance out your question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Is there any other way to post a bug report without having to write something about it?

Comment: Could you propose an alternative? Images are highly inconvenient to readers of your question, especially those on mobile. They can't be copy-pasted and aren't always easy to read. You're really just hurting your chances of people wanting to answer your question by posting errors as images that could easily be text. Additionally, this is not a bug report since it was an issue with your implementation. Real bug reports shouldn't go here either, they should go to Flutter/Dart github issues.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I hope it is correct now.

Comment: Yes that's good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is immutable so it's "read-only" as the error suggests. You have to create a modifiable copy of the list so that the sort function can modify it. Then you can use your existing sort implementation.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> listCopy = List.of(list);

listCopy.sort((a, b) {
  return (a['product_expiration_date']).compareTo(b['product_expiration_date']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
list.sort((a, b) => (b.expiration_date).compareTo(a.expiration_date)); // sort
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 
This is the Problem: 
`The getter 'expiration_date' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.`

Comment: Of course use product_expiration_date, I shortend it

Comment: This does not address the actual issue and creates more. `a` and `b` are maps, which don't have getters that you try to use. The OP's existing method of accessing the map's data was correct.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Oh yes is logical, I did not have the error message as info :(

Comment: @M123 That's something the OP should be providing. Don't answer the question if you don't have the information you need to do so. Flag it for closure, downvote, or comment on the post and wait for the OP to add the info.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thank you, I will keep this in mind in the future.